# java.io.EOFException and count issues in keyReleased handler

Tags: java

While taking input, my text field starts deleting the input and throws a java.io.EOFException. In my `keyReleased` event handler, `count` remains `0`; the handler is not doing the `count++`.

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong and how to resolve this issue?

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int count = 0;
    result = null;
    setVisible(false);
    matchingVector.clear();
    String searchTerm = dialog.getField(getSearchFieldNumber());
    System.out.println(searchTerm);
    if (searchTerm.length() > 0) {
        listModel.removeAllElements();
        System.out.println(recordVector.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < recordVector.size(); i++) {
            if (matchesCriteria(recordVector.get(i), searchTerm)) {
                matchingVector.add(recordVector.get(i));
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            clearFields();
            System.out.println("Bad-bad things happen here?");
        } else if (count == 1) {
            updateFields(matchingVector.get(0));
        } else if (count > 1) {
            validate();
            setVisible(true);
            setSize(WIDTH, Math.min(500, matchingVector.size() * ROW_HEIGHT));
        }
    } else {
        clearFields();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your clearFields() method.

Comment: If count remains     `0` the condition         `matchesCriteria(recordVector.get(i), searchTerm)` never returns true

Comment: private void clearFields() {
  // clear any fields in the dialog
  dialog.setField(2, "");
  dialog.setField(3, "");
  dialog.setField(4, "");

 } @Uli

Comment: @CodeCat so what do i do?

Comment: post your machtesCriteria method pls

Comment: @CodeCat  private boolean matchesCriteria(Record record, String searchTerm) {
  // get a copy of the record and cast it to your data type eg
  Booking booking = (Booking) record; 
  // see if it matches your search term eg
  if (booking.className.toLowerCase().contains(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
  // if it does then add it to the drop down list                                // 
   listModel.addElement(booking.className);
            
   return true;
  } else
   return false;
 }

Comment: @CodeCat did you receive the code?

Comment: I think you are missing a opening bracket so pls add         `{`  after the     `else`

Comment: @CodeCat where ? in matchcriteria?

Comment: @CodeCat it is giving error on closing bracket '}' ???

Comment: Fixed misspellings; made the problem description more readable; removed tag and fluff from title.

Comment: @J0e3gan sorry i could not get you?

Comment: i am near the solution, there is a junk in the class.dat which is a hash file from there i am not able to view the sujjestions

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a opening bracket for the else in   `matchesCriteria`
the follwing code should work
    `private boolean matchesCriteria(Record record, String searchTerm){ 
     Booking booking = (Booking) record; 
     if(booking.className.toLowerCase().contains(searchTerm.toLowerCase())){
     listModel.addElement(booking.className);
     return true;}
     else{return false;}
     }`

Comment: it is still in count=0 with this output

Comment: But does it still throw   `java.io.EOFException` and if yes pls post the `Stacktrace`

Comment: yes it still throwing the exception java.io.EOFException

Comment: pls post the whole output of the excpetion

Comment: java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
m
100
Bad-bad things happen here?

Comment: I can not help you if you post something like this

Comment: java.io.EOFException
m
100
Bad-bad things happen here?

Comment: but this is the output Sir

Comment: Are using a      `try catch` Statement?

Comment: in above posted code , it is always moving to count ==0 then clear all fields and print the statement bad-bad things happen here?